# Gatsby merge graphql data with dynamic data

Tags: graphql, gatsby

I have a site made with gatsby that has some static data ( a catalogue of items ), but at runtime when the user logs in, it makes a request to an api to get a list of items they are entitled to ( this returns just a list of id's.

Is it possible ( and does this make sense to do ) - to:

- return the graphql item data in a normalized list so I can do easy look ups of the item id's and then render out into a list?

So basically

```
items = { 1: { title: 'itemA', price: 1 }, 2: { title: 'itemB', price: 2 }}; // from a Gql query

userItems = [1, 3, 5]; // from a dynamic fetch request

userItems.map(id => <Item {...items[id] } />) // easy lookup of item info
```

I know if I didn't use Gql I could just fetch the json data for the items and either merge it with the user data when the service fetches it, or just do as in my example above as I would control the structure of the json data, I just wanted to make use of gql to learn it, and so the item data could be reused on different pages that might be totally static ( a list of all items for example ) and then I could pick and choose which item attributes I want.

My data currently is an array of items, as if I storred it as a keyed object of items then fed it to gql via the json transformer, each of my nodes were different, so I didn't seem to be able to fetch a list of all items.

Comment: Just to clarify: you basically want your data to be fetched at build time, and only fetch the item keys that a user has access to on the client? You can probably do it, with two caveats: 1. if the items should _not_ be visible by others, you shouldn't fetch them at build time (they'll be in your source); and 2. this won't significantly improve performance, what takes time is the network request, not the payload (for small payloads like yours)

Comment: reusable ... graphql ... dynamic ... apollo client (for dynamic parts) with static (gatsby fetched/collected) data "rendered" as initial cache?

Comment: @RobinMétral sorry no. So what I want is at build time to fetch a list of all items, and stick them in Gql. Then at run time, when a user has logged in to use fetch to query a list of items the user has access to ( this part is ok ) - but then I need to link up the items the user has access to ( the id ) to the item metadata ( from the all items gql response ).

Comment: Normally it would be simple enough to have all items return as a map
```
items = { 1: { name: 'item A' } }
```

then get the ID of the item from the user and just do a simpe lookup. 

But currently Gql returns the data as an array, so I then need to do run through the list of all items to find the id the user has `array.find` vs `object[key]`

Comment: who cares ... write local resolver to do it for you .... while asking for data using simple queries like `userItems{ name, price }`